# Tracking App sessions in mixpanel javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, analytics, tracking, mixpanel

How do I enable App sessions (ae_sessions) in mixpanel-browser library?

I am using mixpanel in a angular application and I want to track total time spent on my website. I can't find how to track ae_sessions in the documentation. In android it's something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com).

it is enabled in settings but it is not tracking:

I tried to find any config() or initialization file but couldn't find it.